# Capybara writing drop down's options texts into an array

Tags: ruby, capybara

I'd like to put a dropdown list's options into an array generically in capybara. After the process I'm expecting to have an arrray of strings, containing all dropdown options. I've tried the code below but the length of my array stays 1 regardless of what the option count is.

```
periods = Array.new()
periods = all('#MainContent_dd')
print periods.length
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The problem is that `all('#MainContent_dd')` returns all elements that have the id `MainContent_dd`. Assuming this is your dropdown and ids are unique, it is expected that the `periods.length` is 1 (ie `periods` is the select list).

What you want to do is get the `option` elements instead of the `select` element.

Assuming your html is:

```
<select id="MainContent_dd">
    <option>Option A</option>
    <option>Option B</option>
    <option>Option C</option>
</select>
```

Then you can do:

```
  periods = find('#MainContent_dd').all('option').collect(&:text)
  p periods.length
  #=> 3
  p periods
  #=> ["Option A", "Option B", "Option C"]
```

What this does is:

1. `find('#MainContent_dd')` - Finds the select list that you want to get the options from
2. `all('option')` - Gets all option elements within the select list
3. `collect(&:text)` - Collects the text of each option and returns it as an array

Comment: Works like a charm :) Thanks Justin , will have more of these noob questions :)

Answer (score 2):

@JustinCo's answer has a problem if used driver isn't fast: Capybara will make a query to driver for every invocation of `text`. So if select contains 200 elements, Capybara will make 201 query to browser instead of 1 which may be slow.

I suggest you to do it using one query with Javascript:

```
periods = page.execute_script("options = document.querySelectorAll('#MainContent_dd > option'); texts=[]; for (i=0; i<options.length; i++) texts.push(options[i].textContent); return texts")
```

or (shorter variant with jQuery):

```
periods = page.evaluate_script("$('#MainContent_dd').map(function() { return $(this).text() }).get()")
```